# Running Sinatra within a MacRuby app

Tags: xcode, xcode4, sinatra, macruby

I'm new to MacRuby with Xcode but I have what I think (hope) is a simple question. I have a small Ruby Sinatra web app that I want to package as a Mac OS packaged application (.app). The application (however it is packaged) is used to read a specific plist file that is apart of Mac OS X Server and display the results through a specific web port in a browser. I don't know if MacRuby is the way to go, but all I need is a simple GUI that starts and stops the Sinatra web app so that users don't have to fuss with the command line (and hopefully without having to install gems, etc). I'm starting to figure out some of the basics of MacRuby and Xcode 4 but I'm not sure where to place the Sinatra ruby file within the Xcode project or how to start it.

I do know how to run a bash command start the ruby server within the application path but not sure if that's the best way or where to actually put the ruby file.

Please forgive my lack of knowledge of desktop development—I really only work in the web world. If I can elaborate on any points, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Control Tower may be your solution:

https://github.com/MacRuby/ControlTower

Part of the macruby project, it does basically what you wish. It's still very new & needs work, but It does function. I have been able to get it to work with sinatra for some test apps but I have yet to try to get any of my actually apps to run thru it (As I am still learning myself)